# Angular testing DOM elements with *ngIf

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

Why does this test pass

```
it ('should hide datatable if data is undefined', () => {
  component.DATA = undefined;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-datatable'))).toBeNull();
});
```

but this doesn't

```
it ('should hide datatable if data is undefined', () => {
  component.DATA = undefined;
  const datatable = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-datatable'));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(datatable).toBeNull();
});
```

For the second test suite I receive following error
Error: Expected DebugElement__POST_R3__({ nativeNode:  }) to be null.

This is the code of the DOM

```
<app-datatable *ngIf="DATA"></app-datatable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has relation with the way you ran Angular's change detection:

- In the first test, you run `fixture.detectChanges()` just after changing `component.DATA`, which I suppose makes some changes in the view.
- In the second test, you first query for the `app-datatable` element and then call `fixture.detectChanges()`. With this sequence, I suppose `datatable` has some content and then it mutates after you call the `detectChanges()`, but as you have accessed it before the change detection the test fails.

Comment: I edited my question. The DATA is used to trigger ngIf, which I would set as undefined so the component won't get rendered. So just to understand you correctly you would suggest that the order of execution in the second test would be: 1. define DATA, 2. fixture.detectChanges(), 3. query datatable, 4. expect().